# Inserting an _invented chromosome in a being to be born in and knowing it will be healthy

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I would like to know whether it could be appropriate to ask whether:

It is possible to make never existing before (in no other human or species), changes to DNA (and the corresponding DNA pair, of course, in the chromosomes), and have expected results and have a healthy being live at the same time.

That is, a chromosome is studied, but is not one that was found. Instead, it was put together, and the result is predictable.

Answer (score 3):

Questions on this site, and across Stack Exchange, are best when they are based on some prior research/reading/work towards a solution that the asker has done.

So, just posting a speculative question about an "invented chromosome" is probably not going to be a good fit. Better to start by reading about e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_biology and asking a *specific question* based on a specific gap in your understanding/knowledge that arises from your efforts to learn about a topic.